# Horizontal dropdown select option menu

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello peoples of StackOverflow. Is it possible to create a `select` menu with that's displayed horizontally with jQuery or CSS.

Something like: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6e1A.jpg]

I tried to do the following CSS:

```
select.horizontal option {
    display: inline-block;
    display*: inline;
}
```

But it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. I think it isn't possible to display the options of a select in a horizontal fashion. However, you might find a custom component, maybe from [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com) or the like, that behaves like a select box but can be styled in various ways. You should provide more information on what you're trying to achieve, and since an image is a good start, I'll gonna upvote your post so you get the needed reputation to embed one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps you:

http://jsfiddle.net/fhbha/

**HTML**

```
<ul id="reg-lists" >
    <li class="one">
        <select><option>Yes</option></select>
        </li> 
    <li class="two">
            <select><option>Yes</option></select>
        </li> 
    <li class="three">
            <select><option>Yes</option></select>
        </li> 
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li {
    display:inline !important;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 10px;    
}
```